# how to decrypt an ordinary folder (not home, nor partition, nor .Private)

Tags: mount, ecryptfs

Following the procedure described [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-encrypt-directories-with-ecryptfs-on-ubuntu-16-04/) I could create an encrypted folder in an external drive.

```
mount -t ecryptfs /media/foo/bar /media/foo/bar
```

Then I put some stuff inside, restarted my computer and I now get a few folders named

```
 ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbqvPj9ejI71-QEsY3Zgt7-TRG7S-ek830T453HKzNQPfJjZVpbWWaxlE--
```

Which I don't know how to mount again.
All tutorials I look for speak about encrypted partitions, encrypted `.Private` folders or encrypted `/home/<user>`

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use the exact same line of command. But !
Also to remember all the parameters passed at the first mount...

```
Select cipher: 
 1) aes: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 etc.

Select key bytes: 
 1) 16
 etc.

Enable plaintext passthrough (y/n) [n]: 
Enable filename encryption (y/n) [n]: y
Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [abcdefcbaa123456]:
```

and the passphrase of course